# function to remove attributes for multiple different elements(which are not child elements) in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for dynamic function which can remove something like **"style"** attribute to multiples different elements at a time which are not child elements. Like below I have script for adding multiple attributes to element. Same way removing attribute to multiple different elements like removeAttributes(el1, el2, el3,  { "style" }); or you can write any script which is right way to do.

```
<script>
function setAttributes(el, options) {
    Object.keys(options).forEach(function(attr) {
        el.setAttribute(attr, options[attr]);
    })
}
setAttributes(img, {
    "src": "../images/...",
    "title": "image title",
    "alt": "text"
});       
<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function in which you can loop through all the elements and remove the attribute by using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute):

```js
function removeAttributes(attr, ...element) {
  element.forEach(function(el){
    el.removeAttribute(attr);
  });
}
var title = document.querySelector('.title');
var el = document.querySelectorAll('img');
var cat = el[0];
var rat = el[1];
removeAttributes('style', title, cat, rat);
```

```html
<div class="title" style="font-size: 19px; border: 1px solid purple;">Animals</div>
<img class="cat" src="/" alt="cat" style="color:red">
<img class="rat" src="/" alt="rat" style="color:blue">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the elements in as an array and then the second arguments as the attribute name you want to remove.

Here is a working example below.

JavaScript

```
function removeAttribute(elements, attributeName) {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute(attributeName);
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const elements = [
    document.getElementById('one'),
    document.getElementById('two'),
    document.getElementById('three')
  ];

  removeAttribute(elements, 'class');
})
```

HTML

```
<a id="one" class="one">Link 1</a>
<a id="two" class="two">Link 2</a>
<a id="three" class="three">Link 3</a>
```

If you inspect the elements, you will see they no longer have the class attribute.